# Python Get key of nested dictionary with highest value for attribute

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem. In my code, I have the following dictionary:

```
{1: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}, 2: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}, 3: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}, 4: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}, 5: {'amount': 41, 'quantity': 0}, 6: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}, 7: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}, 8: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}, 9: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}, 10: {'amount': 40.0, 'quantity': 0}}
```

Out of this dictionary, I need to grab the key of the inner dictionary with the greatest `amount`. In my case, that should be `5`. I found a lot about things like this, but nothing about nested dictionaries.

I came up with something like this:

```
max(int(i['amount']) for i in dict.values())
```

But this returns the highest `amount`. I need to return the key of that dictionary with that `amount`. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the maximum among the keys of your dictionary, comparing based on a custom key parameter that retrieves the amount corresponding to the key:

```py
result = max(data.keys(), key=lambda x: data[x]['amount'])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could check if the value is equal to the max and then save the key, e.g.,:

```
[k for k, v in dict.items() if v == max(int(v['amount'])]
```

This will give you a list of all the keys with the max-value (if multiple share a max)-- so to just get one you could index the 0th element of it.